# Downloading and using a Python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have setup and successfully used a virtual environment with Python using virtualenv. However, I had to change the directory of my project, which involved uploading it to AWS CodeCommit, and then downloading it, to the new location, on my computer.

I try to use `source env/bin/activate`, but that appears to try to activate the old virtualenv. After `pip freeze`, I get the following output:

```
$ pip freeze
zsh: /Users/path/to/NEW/environment/env/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /Users/path/to/OLD/environment/env/bin/python3: no such file or directory
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -yYAML 5.2 (/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-yYAML=='": Expected W:(abcd...)
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ix 1.13.0 (/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-ix==1.1'": Expected W:(abcd...)
autopep8==1.4.3
awscli==1.16.309
awsebcli==3.17.0
...all my other packages.....
virtualenv==16.7.9
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.57.0
```

Is there a way that I can activate the environment that I downloaded? Do I have to add it to PATH? Additionally, do I have to delete or alter something to make my old virtual environment disappear?

I have looked at the virualenv documentation. Will `setup_python` be of any use here?

Comment: You generally don't transfer a virtualenv from one location to another; you just re-create it in your target location.

Comment: Thankyou @larsks. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.